# Desktop Windows Manager causes severe game lag

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10, space-engine

I have a Dell Inspiron 7501 with the following specifications:

OS: Windows 10

Processor: intel core i7-10750

Memory: 16 GB RAM

Graphics: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650

For the past few months I have been facing some problems while playing a 3D game called SpaceEngine on my computer. The game lags severely and the FPS drops to as low as 6. To pinpoint the issue I opened up Task Manager and found something weird.

In the rare instance that the game does NOT lag which does happen sometimes, the Task Manager showed the following stats,

[image]

The GPU usage of the game was around 80-83% and the Desktop Windows Manager's (DWM) GPU usage was around 13.5%. However when the game DOES lag, the Task Manager is as follows,

[image]

Now the game has a spiked GPU usage of 100% and the Desktop Windows Manager is only using 0.8% of the GPU. I have seen this correlation between the game's FPS drop and this change in the GPU usage of the game and the DWM several times.

Why is this happening? Why does DWM's GPU usage suddenly drop while simultaneously spiking the game's GPU usage and causing massive lags and FPS drops in the game? What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Why do you think DWM using _fewer_ resources would be an indicative of it being the cause of sluggish behavior? I think it's more likely that the game is getting into a situation it has to do a lot of calculations and is claiming all of the available GPU, causing DWM to give it up -- and your system simply doesn't have sufficient resources for all of its multitasking causing fps to drop.

Comment: This game has worked perfectly fine on my system for almost a year. But the problem has only begun in the last month or two. I haven't changed anything in my computer in any substantial way. Moreover to your point that the game maybe claiming the entire GPU for itself might be possible but then again, the game makes use of GPU-1 which is NVIDIA while DWM makes use of GPU-0 which is Intel. If the game never uses GPU-0 then why does DWM stop using it? Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you applied any windows updates, even in the background? (Start Menu, type 'Updates', go to the system updates page and check to see when they were last installed.) Check your antivirus for when it last ran or if it might be trying to lock game files when you're using them. Also graphics drivers, check that they're up to date and when they were last updated. Might also want to do an actual health check on your graphics card just in case, especially if this is "out of the blue".

Comment: You can limit the time you use it and then use another thing. But if necessary, I'm not going to force you to stop it(End the Task).

Comment: Do you by chance use an Xbox Series X controller for your games? I had a problem with one recently where DWM would fault and crash badly, and then minimize whatever game I was playing (DS3 at the time). The solution was to update the firmware for the controller with an Xbox Accessories app.